# Since Blender 2.90, the program has been very slow to start up

Tags: performance

So ever since Blender 2.90 came out, and with the following updates of 2.91 and 2.92, Blender has been very slow to startup... At least more than 30 seconds, probably closer to a minute. Blender itself runs fine, and performance hasn't changed. I thought it might have been a PC issue, but it happens on multiple computers.

Any thoughts on what it could be?

Comment: what do you mean "at startup" - with opening your special file or just Blender default startup? I haven't made this oberservation....

Comment: I still use it on my 11 year old PC sometimes and there is no noticeable difference. All my computers have SSDs.